# Functional algorithm to reverse a number

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I've been playing with Clojure lately and I can't get this algorithm to work:

```
(defn reverse-number [number reversed]
   (if (= number 0)
     reversed
     (reverse-number (/ number 10) 
                     (+ (rem number 10) (* reversed 10)))))
```

This is how I should call it `(reverse-number 123 0)` and the result I expect is: `321`.
When I run this, **the REPL just hangs**.

**Can someone explain me, please, what is happening, what I did wrong and how to get this function working?**

**Note**: I know I can use string functions to reverse a number. Actually, I already did this, but I'm not interested in this solution. All I want is to make the leap to functional languages. That's why I try multiple approaches.

Using **string functions**:

```
(defn reverse-number [n]
  (Integer. (clojure.string/reverse (str n))))

(reverse-number 123)  ; --> 321
```

I **don't like this version** since it **feels like cheating** by using the string version of reverse.

Comment: What would `3210` be in reverse?

Comment: @Gumbo: `123`, why? This is the answer I expect. I certainly wouldn't expect `0123` since that wouldn't be a correct number...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [quot](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/quot) instead of `/`.

`/` in clojure will give you a fraction so `number` will never be 0 (unless it's 0 from the beginning), while `quot` will give you "integer division".

Examples:

```
user=> (/ 123 10)                  
123/10
user=> (quot 123 10)
12
```

Comment: +1 - I was just about to ask how Clojure implemented truncating division.